# Can't load python extension module that exists

Tags: python, python-import, python-extensions

I'm trying to use thanos, which creates an extension module at runtime.  Thanos is constantly failing as it cannot import that said extension it created at runtime.

I am baffled as to why this is the case.

At runtime (after compilation) the "cutils_ext" dir contains `cutils_ext.so`

`import cutils_ext` works, but `import cutils_ext.cutils_ext` fails with

```
ImportError: No module named cutils_ext
```

I've tested with with imp directly.  Say that cutils is the imported cutils_ext package.
When I do:

```
imp.find_module('cutils_ext', cutils.__path__)
```

I again get the :

```
ImportError: No module named cutils_ext
```

I am completely baffled. Is there any way to debug this? I cannot run python in verbose mode due to my inability to start the python interpreter (using picloud), but if I could enable verbose at runtime, that would help (haven't figured out how to do that).

Comment: Is the Python version that Thanos linked its module with the same as you are using?  For example, the entry point protocol differes between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Yes, all are python2.7. I was even able to download the extension to my own computer and load it directly. Either way, it seems the find_module is failing, even before the load occurs

Comment: Wow, my bad. Looks like I had another cutils_ext elsewhere on sys,path and Theano was preloading it.  Filed a bug on Theano ( https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try:

```
import cutils_ext
import cutils_ext.cutils_ext
```

I don't know why, but sometimes I also have to import a module in order to import the sub modules in it.

Or maybe, just maybe, the second cutils_ext doesn't exist at all in the first cutils_ext?

EDIT:
Wait a minute.. could you please post your folder structure and what the PYTHONPATH is containing?

I guess you have something like:

```
upper_folder (a folder)
    cutils_ext (folder)
        __init__.py (file)
        cutils_ext.so (obviously file)
```

if your PYTHONPATH points to **upper_folder** then you should be able to do what you have posted Note that if you have this situation the __ init __.py **must** be there.

If however your PYTHONPATH is pointing directly to the cutils_ext folder, then I supposed you can only import the file, so cutils_ext.cutils_ext doesn't make sense for the interpreter (unless you have a variable called cutils_ext in cutil_ext.so...)

Comment: "Or maybe, just maybe, the second cutils_ext doesn't exist at all in the first cutils_ext?"  Good call.  It was very subtle as theano was preloading my cutils_ext package from another location, then patching sys.path.  cutils_ext therefore referred to the wrong package. ugh.. thanks for the post.. helped a lot!